# Unable to set breakpoints in Chrome dev tools, version 26.0.1410.64 m

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, breakpoints, google-chrome-devtools

I need to debug some JavaScript an' I use Chrome dev tools. I'm a newby in JavaScript (just started to learn a couple of days ago), an' at work I could set breakpoints via the Resources pane. But at home for some reason I can't do this: after the click no breakpoint appeares.

I have Chrome version: 26.0.1410.64 m.

What could be the case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm a fool! haha! breakpoints are set in the `Source` pane )))

Comment: Thank you... debugged 1000 times before! I too am a fool!

Answer (score 81):

clicking on the De-Obfuscate Source button (i.e. {}) solved this issue for me.

Comment: Also known as "Pretty print" - but yes, this was my not-exactly-intuitive problem also.

Comment: Ha, ha ... I just had this issue, and I came across your post ... and I realized that I had already given it an upvote over a year ago.  So much for learning from my mistakes.  But thanks, again!

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while, but in version 33.0.1750.146, but my problem was that I was on the `Sources` pane (I'd call this a tab; it's one of the items at the very top of the window), but I was on the `Content scripts` tab (on the left hand side). I needed to switch to the `Sources` tab.

To be clear, there are two sets of `Sources` tabs; one is within the other.

**UPDATE 2016-01-07:** Now I'm on 47.0.2526.106. The only thing that worked for me today was to close DevTools and re-open. It was a little finicky. It worked once, then stopped, and I had to close the DevTools and re-open again. I saw @johntrepreneur's answer about closing the browser, but unfortunately I have too many tabs open on too many workspaces, so that's too much of a pain, so I didn't try that, although I have to assume that would work.

Comment: Yeah, yesterday downloaded this version. It can mislead developers at the first time:)

Comment: Thank you. This saved my day. Close and open devtools - such a weird bug!

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions didn't work for me. Had to close and restart browser to be able to set breakpoints again.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when there is a JS error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of weird built in function in windows 10 i think because I did press a few buttons by accident. Some of my keys even stopped working in certain areas of visual studio. F.e the letter "c" stopped working in the find window.

Mine did this and no solution worked, i pressed alt, windows key and function key a few times and my problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed as follows:  For me, the issue stems from having set up Chrome to interact with operating system files.  If you set this up, then the fact is evident from a green dot by the file name.  At some point, I could not set a breakpoint in a recently edited file.  I fixed this by disconnecting the interaction, as follows:  When viewing "sources", above the code, there were some file names listed.  Clicking the [x] to make the particular filename go away gave a caution message; I proceeded without saving.  After that, I was able to set breakpoints for that file.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. However, once I closed the popup message in my browser, suddenly all my breakpoints that I set in that time appeared. Mental note: Don't set breakpoints while your app is showing a popup.

Answer (score -3):

I couldn't find any direct fix for this problem.
It seems that chrome keeps settings of your site stored somewhere whatever you do to clean it. (I tried removing the folder from workspace, closing et reopening chrome etc... and nothing worked).
A workaround is to change your site's url to make chrome consider it a new site